# Battery nominal capacity estimation using Coulomb Counting and Matlab lsqnonlin

Tags: batteries, matlab, soc

I'm trying to estimate the nominal capacity of a PV plant battery pack collecting SOC data from the BMS using current discharge. Once I've collected current, time and SOC data I put those data into matlab and use an optimization algorithm to evaluate the capacity using the following expression (in the attachment) and the following code:

```
%% Optimization phase
clear all;
clc;
%% Estimation procedure using LSQNONLIN with two possible approach evaluated 
% in 'SOCestimation.m': (1) Estimate the C by comparing the REAL SOC (filtered)
% and the one evaluated with CC in each single point till the end; (2) Evaluate C as
% same as before but considering the specific EOD (End of Discharge) point.
% x = C_estimated for battery pack (React) in Ah
x = 5;
x0 = rand*[x];
% Capacity (x stands for unknown) lower and upper bounds
xlb=[1];
xub=[50];
% Setting the optimization alg.
options = optimset('MaxFunEvals',15000,'MaxIter',10,'TolFun',1e-100,'TolX',1e-100,'Algorithm', 'levenberg-marquardt','Display','iter-detailed', 'FinDiffType', 'central'); %'levenberg-marquardt'
[x,resnorm,residual,exitflag,output]=lsqnonlin(@SOCestimation, x0, [xlb], [], options);
```

---

```
%% Soc estimation file
function [f] = SOCestimation(x)
%% Loading OCV curve (discharge curves at 200 W during 02/03 november)
%% Filtering the SOC_real from a stepped curve into a linear one (can be commented out)
% 
% y = smooth(SOC, 1e100, 'moving');
% filt_len = 1;
% a = 1;
% b = (1/filt_len)*ones(1,filt_len);
% SOC_real_filtered = filter(b,a,y);
%% Evaluate SOC as a function of C in Ah (=x) and the difference between SOC real
% and calculated (Discharge current is negative)
    
SOC_estim = ((1-(1/(x*3600))*cumtrapz(Time, -Current))*100);
% Estimate the C by comparing the real SOC (filtered or not) with the Coulomb Counting one
% considering also the last SOC value (End of Discharge)
f=SOC_real-SOC_estim;
plot(Time,SOC_real,Time,SOC_estim)
legend({'Real SOC filtered from stepped function','SOC estimated studying the C'})
drawnow
end
```

In the code presented the "End of Discharge" point for matching the real SOC with the calculated one is (eventually) used because the BMS reports a drop in the real SOC at the end of discharge from around 10% to 5%.

The problem is that I'm analyzing different discharge curves (1kW, 200W, 2kW constant power discharge) and I'm obtaining always different nominal capacity:

- 16.06 Ah for 1kW discharge;
- 15.9 Ah for 200W discharge;
- 14.97 Ah for 2kW discharge.

From the datasheet I've got that this battery pack has 4.8 kWh initial capacity and 288V as nominal voltage so nominal initial capacity is 16.8Ah but during lifetime is reported that the nominal capacity is around 4.0 kWh and 4.4 kWh so 13.8Ah - 15.4 Ah.

Please..what is wrong with my code? I'm trying to estimate the maximum capacity of the battery in order to evaluate for example the state of health comparing it to a new battery pack.

Here is the data I'm using (from [this link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HXQ1EYHmRBnHt0gjFOkHciMrhFlX1qv1?usp=sharing)):

1. For 1kW discharge: R1_19_ott.mat
2. For 200W discharge: R1_02_nov.mat
3. For 2kW discharge: data_R1_15-11-2022.mat

In this data files the variable "Time" is expressed as "Tempo" and "Current" as "Corrente".

And also following is the expression used (as image).

[image]

Additionally, here is an example of SOC fitting (then C estimation) using 1kW discharge (the blue one is the SOC from BMS data):
[image]

Comment: Please include a plot of your data compared to the estimates.  My experience is that when you do this, very often you find your equation is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I've added the results from the SOC estimation with 1kW constant power discharge, comparing the SOC calculated with the real one obtained from BMS data.

Comment: Nothing? Please

Comment: I don't see a problem with the code or your estimates, and all your estimates match to within a few percent.   You're doing a bit better than the lifetime capacity indicates.